# All virtualhosts serving Apache default files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.2

I'm trying to configure Apache as an in-network webserver, and am using the sites-available/sites-enabled feature as opposed to just static vhost files.  I set up a couple VirtualHosts, all with a unique DocumentRoot, however request for all the VirtualHosts just serve up the "It's Working!" default file.  I can't for the life of me figure out why it won't serve the content out of the correct directory.  Here's the contents of the virtualhost directive files, let me know if I need to post more.

`default` (note that apache renames this to `000-default` in sites-enabled, so it's not an ordering issue)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
ServerName emp

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 ServerName emp
 DocumentRoot /var/www

 <Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
 </Directory>
 <Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
 </Directory>

 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
 <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
  AllowOverride None
  Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

 # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
 # alert, emerg.
 LogLevel warn

 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

`billmed`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName billmed.emp
 ServerRoot /home/empression/Projects/billmed/web/httpdocs

 <Directory "/home/empression/Projects/billmed/web/httpdocs">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from All
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that I have DNS zones for both `emp` and `billmed.emp`, as well as entries in /etc/hosts.  My ultimate goal is to set up this machine as an in-house webserver with a custom tld (emp), but progress has been pretty slow.

### Some more info

`/etc/hosts` entries

```
#custom-sites
192.168.1.100 emp
192.168.1.100 billmed.emp
```

`ports.conf`

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

#NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

`ls -l sites-enabled`

```
empression@empression-server1:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ ls -l ../sites-enabled/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 2010-05-22 12:36 000-default -> ../sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 2010-05-22 13:33 billmed -> ../sites-available/billmed
```

### Update 2010-06-16

I wasn't able to work on this for a few weeks, but I have tried all the solutions posted below as of now, and am still unable to fix the problem so I have added a bounty.

### Update

Here's the output of `apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`

```
empression@empression-server1:~$ apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Mon Jul 12 14:29:01 2010] [warn] NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 has no VirtualHosts
VirtualHost configuration:
192.168.1.100:80       is a NameVirtualHost
         default server billmed.emp (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/billmed:1)
         port 80 namevhost billmed.emp (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/billmed:1)
Syntax OK
```

Comment: Weird question perhaps, but is there actually a line `Include sites-enabled/` in apache.conf / httpd.conf?

Comment: Can you send dump of "apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS" command ? 
Maybe we are really missing something important.

Comment: i've updated my previous answer.

Answer (score 8):

In virtual host definition file, correct the line below.

`ServerRoot /home/empression/Projects/billmed/web/httpdocs`
to
`DocumentRoot /home/empression/Projects/billmed/web/httpdocs`

Use DocumentRoot directive to serve virtualhost. 
here is the link for more information 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html

---

Update your virtualhost definition (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/billmed) as following,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName billmed.emp
 DocumentRoot /home/empression/Projects/billmed/web/httpdocs

 <Directory "/home/empression/Projects/billmed/web/httpdocs">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from All
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I added the output of apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS, see my updated post

Answer (score 5):

@yasin is correct; you need to have your VirtualHosts specify a [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#documentroot) ('...the directory from which httpd will serve files...')not a [ServerRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#serverroot) ('...the directory in which the server lives. Typically it will contain the subdirectories conf/ and logs/....')

There might be another problem *also*, but that part is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

What is your mapping in `/etc/hosts` or in DNS configuration ? Try replacing `*` with `127.0.0.1` I mean `<VirtaulHost 127.0.0.1:80>` and `NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80`.
What is in your `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` ? Check if all symlinks are in place. for instance: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/<yoursite.emp>`

**EDIT:**

Try this:
In `ports.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 127.0.0.1:80

NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.100:80
Listen 192.168.1.100:80
```

Then in `000-default`: `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>`
In `billmed`: `<VirtualHost 192.168.1.100:80`

Comment: Thanks, see me edit.  Also, would using a statically typed IP in the VirtualHost directive really help?

Comment: I have similar configuration. It works. It is different from yours only in using IP addresses in `ports.conf`, `VirtualHost` and `NameVirtualHost`

Comment: I changed every instance of `*:80` to `127.0.0.1:80` and still have the same results. :(

Comment: ok. look at my EDIT.

Comment: Ugh, I figured having unique IPs would force it serve different content.  Nothing.  There must be something I'm missing here.

Comment: I simulated your situation and it works. I'm referring to initial configuration with `*:80`. I enabled `NameVirtualHost *:80` in `ports.conf` and get rid of it in first line of `000-default` . I deleted also second line with `ServerName` so `000-default` begins from `<VirtualHost>` directive. Of course my lan IP address is different but all works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I would add mask rather than concrete IP to the host file:

```
#/etc/hosts/

# custom-sites
127.0.0.1 emp
127.0.0.1 billmed.emp
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the **ServerRoot** to **DocumentRoot** in **billmed** file.

Add/Move your **billmed** vhost config in /etc/apache2/sites-available/.

Then enable the **billmed** vhost like this:

```
sudo a2ensite billmed
```

Restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Edit:** changed a2enmod into a2ensite, stupid typo : )

Comment: that should be `a2ensite` (to enable a site), not `a2enmod` (to enable a module)

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you've tried everything else, make sure that you're including the sites-enabled folder from your main apache configuration file.

Also, if you disable everything but the billmed virtual host, can you get it to server files from that directory?

Answer (score 0):

Are there any Alias directives which point / to /var/www that are in the global config as opposed to being inside a virtualhost section?

Comment: No, I grepped all the config files and there are no Aliases for `/` nor any that point to `/var/www/`.

Answer (score 0):

NameVirtualHost is commented out.

If you are setting up  containers for each, and using ServerName/ServerAlias, you'll need to uncomment that, restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

You HUP'd apache after creating the new site file, so that the running daemon re-read its config?